# from kubectl config view, extract the server url corresponding to the cluster referenced by a context

Tags: kubectl

I have the name of a kubectl context.  I want the "server" url corresponding to the cluster referred to by the context.

Given the context name, I can get the name of the cluster with

```
kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.contexts[?(@.name=="contextname")].context.cluster}'
```

Given a cluster name, I can do:

```
kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.clusters[?(@.name=="clustername")].cluster.server}'
```

How can I do this in a single "kubectl config view" call?  I essentially want the second call to have a nested template instead of the hardcoded "clustername".

Comment: Try configuring the URL to a proxy server to use for requests made by this client in the kubeconfig : `kubectl config set-cluster my-cluster-name --proxy-url=my-proxy-url`

Comment: Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know if the above comments help to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Comment: If it matters, my question has become moot because I figured out how to reconfigure things so that I don't have to do a "double dereference", but I frankly have no clue how your comment is supposed to address my question.

Comment: The above comment is based on **Komodor post** : [kubectl config Explained: How to Configure Cluster Access](https://komodor.com/learn/kubectl-config-explained-how-to-configure-cluster-access) go through this post for more details, which may help to resolve your issue.